# Why do I have to explicitly call jquery and bootstrap in my Nuxt.js plugin when its loaded globally in vendor?

Tags: nuxt.js

I am facing a strange issue, as described in the question.

When I did this:

```
plugins: [
    '~plugins/posh.js'
  ],
vendor: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'popper.js'],
    plugins: [
      // set shortcuts as global for bootstrap
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
```

It appears that it doesn't globally load jquery or bootstrap

I have to load it up manually in my plugin (**posh.js)** like this.

```
if (process.client) {
require('bootstrap')
const $ = require('jquery')
..some jquery and bootstrap code specific to a theme.
}
```

This doesn't make sense. Why would that need to be done.

Answer (score 1):

no need to add into vendor just put your jquery file into folder and make your nuxt.config.js like below.

```
head: {
    script: [{
      src: '/global/resources/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
    }, {
      src: '/global/resources/jquery-ui.min.js'
    }, {
      src: '/global/resources/bootstrap.min.js'
    }]
  }
```

So everything will fine, no need to add into vendor and no need to mention into webpack plugin because you want to use jquery so any pages and everywhere you can use, in this way jquery file always add on top of your every pages, enjoy!

Comment: This doesn’t perform concatenation